# dynamodb update item based on 3 columns

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

i have a table with custID and sensor as my primary and sort keys

```
custID      sensor      data          date
joe           123       wind       01/01/1901
mary          456       rain       01/02/1901
```

now when a new record comes like below

new row:

```
joe, 123, temp, 01/04/1901
```

update row:

```
joe, 123, wind, 01/07/1901
```

I want to enter it as a new row, but if the data column matches, i want to update the row. Now if i change my keys to sensor and data, this will work, but how would i do this with the current keys?

my actual data structure is much more complicated than this, but i wanted to keep it simple for the question.

```
var updateExpressions =[];
updateExpressions.push("#data"+counter+"=:data"+counter+", #date"+ counter +" = :date"+ counter);
attrNames["#data"+ counter] = "data";
attValues[":data"+ counter] = data;

attrNames["#date"+ counter] = "date";
attValues[":date"+ counter] = date;
counter++;
```

then in load params

```
var loadparamsP = {

    TableName: "mytable",
    Key: { sensor: sensor, custID: custID},
    ExpressionAttributeNames:attrNames,
    ExpressionAttributeValues:attValues,
    UpdateExpression:"SET "+ updateExpressions,
   ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
};
dynamo.updateItem(loadparamsP, function(err,res){
console.log(res + "res");
        if (err)
            callback(err)
        else{
            callback(null, 'Data inserted');

        }
});
```

EDIT:
So i'm making some headway, with this and i think i'm getting close

So any relevant help and not just random posts claimed as answers would be helpful

Comment: Is there a reason you keep posting completely irrelevant things? The two posts are in no way related!!!!! are you farming for rep or something, which is what it seems and your other posts, which kept getting downvoted, you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that you may try is to create a GSI that will allow to query data using you data column matches.

Then you can query an item using this GSI and if data is there, you can update the item and write it back.

The only potential drawback is that this is basically a check-then-act, which may or may not be an issue for you. If this is an issue, you could try to use [DynamoDB transactions](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions), but they are only implemented for Java client and [have high cost](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions/blob/master/DESIGN.md).